# Twitter bootstrap dropdown toggle and url?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Reading the documentation for twitter bootstrap on dropdowns I saw that it said you can have the url stay intact for the dropdown toggle. I have tried to accomplish this but haven't had any luck with it working. Instead it just toggles the dropdown menu instead of that path it's supposed to be going on. What am I missing? Here is an example of my code.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dPublisher" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-target="#" href="publisher.php">PUBLISHER<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledbyid="dPublisher">
        <li><a href="eeditions.php">E-Editions</a></li>
    <li><a href="digitalarchive.php">Digital Archive</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="blog.php">BLOG</a></li>
```

In this example PUBLISHER is supposed to be the dropdown trigger and a link while BLOG is just a link. The dropdown menus work and all the links inside work but I can't get the url to stay intact like it says in the documentation. Am I not understanding the documentation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but it seems to work as expected: http://www.bootply.com/64937 Can you clarify what you mean by "stay intact"?

Comment: That's why I'm wondering if I don't understand the documentation. The href for PUBLISHER doesn't actually navigate to the page it refers to. Everytime I click on it, it will toggle open and toggle close the dropdown but no redirection. I wanted it to toggle open the dropdown and then if clicked again redirect to publisher.php. Am I not understanding the documentaion correctly and is it not supposed to do that?

Comment: I think it's either navigate to link or toggle dropdown but not both. You could probably use jquery click event handler to handle your special case.

Comment: Ah ok I was afraid of that. I thought it was too good to be true to do it without jQuery. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onClick event, as mentioned, but you'll want it disabled for mobile views.  If you're using the Bootstrap navBar, for instance, you can do the following after adding a ".clickable-dropdown" class to your toggle trigger:

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(window).resize(function(){
                        if($(window).width() >= 920){
                            $('.clickable-dropdown').on('click', function(){
                                window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
                            });
                        }else{
                            $('.clickable-dropdown').on('click', function(){
                                return false;
                            })
                        }
                    }).resize();
                });
```

This will allow the drop-down to work on mobile devices with the touch event, and not capture the click's normal function.  Unfortunately, this seems to be a limitation of Bootstrap's dropdown script and if you need better functionality, you're better off just using one of the many other CSS or jQuery based drop-down menus.